Change the sheet size/shape in Altium PCB editor
In Altium PCB editor you can make the 'sheet' visible by opening the View Configuration ('l') and enabling the 'Sheet Line/Area Color'.  This places a white (by default) area behind the PCB.  How do you change the size and shape of this area?

Find the "Properties" panel, select the board, and scroll all the way down to the "Other" section, and "Sheet Settings" sub-section.
The sheet can either be set numerically, or from the "Sheet Layer".
This is also clearly outlined in the official documentation: PCB Environment Setup


The "Sheet" layer is just like any other mechanical layer (see the "View Configuration" panels -> "Layers & Colors"), and you'll probably need to add it manually unless you have a template setup.
After drawing an outline, uncheck and re-check the "Get Size From Sheet Layer" box (or close/re-open the PCB), and Altium will then use the extremes of whatever you place on that layer for the sheet's edges.

Thanks, I was looking at the properties, but failed to scroll all the way down, and I went through the same Altium page also but missed it there too.
These are strange settings, since the X/Y coordinates don't seem to relate to the origin, and if I deselect the 'Get Size...' option, change the values, and then select it again, the numbers don't change back.  Where are the 'sheet layer' settings it refers to?

I see the X/Y coordinates are based on the Absolute Origin, not the user-defined one which explains the first part.

I've updated my answer with additional details
